# Why rs.send is showing error based on string input inside it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new at node and express and was just trying to create a HTML form which take two numbers and display its result using "express" and "node". When I write `rs.send(result)` I get the following error

[image]

This is also displayed is my browser both shown when I press calculate button. Strangely `Invalid status code: 2` shown in the picture is my answer to the calculation.
This message is not shown when I type `rs.send("The answer is" + result)` and everything runs smoothly.

My question why is this happening and what is the reason behind it?

This is my full code:-

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  var num1 =Number(req.body.num1);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
  var result = num1+num2;
  res.send(result);
})

app.get('/bmicalculator', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/bmiCalculator.html");
});

app.post("/bmicalculator", function(req, res){
  var num1 =Number(req.body.height);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.weight);
  var result = num1+num2;
  res.send(result);
})



app.listen(port);
```

PS:- Ignore BMI calculator, it is doing simple addition.

Comment: I think `res.send(data)` requires the data to be a `string`, `object` or `Buffer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.send(data)` wants the `data` you pass it to be one of the following:

```
String
Object
Buffer
Array
```

If you pass it a Number, it thinks you're trying to use an older, now deprecated form of `res.send(status)` that allowed you to pass a number and it would be treated as the status code.  You can see how the code detects that case [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L129) in the code for `res.send()`.

So, moral of the story is to pass `res.send()` the type of data it wants in order to function properly.  If you want to pass a number, then convert it to a string before calling `res.send()`.  Keep in mind that an http response is sent as string data anyway so somewhere along the line, your number has to be converted to a string anyway.

Comment: But isn't Number() is also an global object. It says so right [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: @BhavyaBudhia - I'm not sure what that has to do with anything.  If you do `let x = Number(11); console.log(typeof x);`, it will show a "number" for the type.  `res.send()` does not take that type of data.  Convert your number to a string before calling `res.send()`.